# What is the best standard to add royalty to NFT on each sell utilizing candy machine?

Tags: nft

What is the best standard to add royalty to NFT on each sale utilizing candy machine or any standard that would be efficient and supported by the top NFT marketplaces?

Answer (score 1):

In the candymachine [docs](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/how-to-guides/my-first-candy-machine-part1): you can see that you will be asked

> `? What is the seller fee basis points? ›`

> The seller fee basis points is the amount of royalty we want to charge on secondary sales (all sales after the candy machine minting). Basis points are percentage times 100, so e.g. 500 basis points is 5%, and 150 is 1.5%. Input the value you wish to use for this and press "enter" to go to the next step.

So you're already setting up royalties for your NFT if you decide to go with CandyMachine to set up your collection.

To make sure that people will pay royalties on each sale you need to use `pNFT` as [Standard](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/token-standard#the-programmable-non-fungible-standard)

> This standard is similar to the Non-Fungible standard above, except that the underlying token account is kept frozen at all times to ensure nobody can transfer, lock or burn Programmable NFTs without going through the Token Metadata program. This enables creators to define custom authorization rules for their NFTs such as enforcing secondary sales royalties.

**NB: This token Standard is supported by all the NFT marketplaces on Solana**